# codeigniter 3 too many redirects when on different port

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl

Normally my codeigniter runs on port 443.

But I have a few pages I want to get the client SSL certificate, so I created a vhost on 8443.

With PHP file outside of code igniter I can visit and get out the certificate information of the client.

However when I visit codeigniter page I get the error:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

My `base_url` is setup as:

```
$config['base_url'] = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : '';
```

I also tried to set this empty so codeigniter fetches itself:

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

But this still shows the same error.

Anyone a pointer what could be going wrong?

**Update**

I changed `HTTP_HOST` to `SERVER_NAME`, but it redirected the traffic to :8443 to the default without the port appended to URL.

So I have added the following code:

```
$port = $_SERVER['HTTP_PORT'];
if($port == "8443")
     $config['base_url'] = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].":8443" : ''; 
 else
     $config['base_url'] = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] : '';
```

The port stays appended to the URL now but I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare __autoload() (previously declared in
>   /bxs/www/application/config/config.php:380) in
>   /bxs/www/application/config/config.php on line 380

**Update 2**

In the end managed to fix it, had to change the following:

`config.php`

```
$port = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
if($port == "8443")
     $config['base_url'] = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].":8443" : ''; 
 else
     $config['base_url'] = isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] : '';
```

`ssl.php`

```
if(!in_array($class,$exclude)) {
  // redirecting to ssl.
  $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
  if (($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) && ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 8443)) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
}
```

Because there was no entry for 8443 on SSL this kept redirecting, by adding the 8443 to the if clause it was solved.

Comment: Try using $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] instead of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
Let me know if it helped so I post a more concrete answer. Thanks

Comment: This helps partially, I updated my main post with my findings.